# Command_button in VBA inside vs Shape with Assigned Macro

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, commandbutton

I am trying to write a script for extracting data from web inside a userform. I am using Get Data From Web option in Excel (2019). The data gets updated when I refresh it manually or even when I do it with a macro assigned Autoshape. However, I have pasted the same code from the macro for a CommandButton that is inside my Userform. My intention is to refresh the data when I click the CommandButton. But when I click it, the background query keeps on running and doesn't terminate.

This is the code for a macro (for REFRESH DATA autoshape)

```
Sub refresh()
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - stocklist").refresh
End Sub
```

This is the code inside my Userform (for REFRESH and GET commandbuttons). The GET button does a kind of Vlookup and works fine.

```
Private Sub cmd_refresh_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - stocklist").refresh
End Sub


Private Sub cmd_get_Click()
txt_script.Text = UCase(txt_script.Text)
For Each cell In Range("Table_stock[Symbol]")
'For Each cell In Range("A1:I220")
    If cell = txt_script.Value Then
   txt_ltp.Value = cell.Offset(0, 4)
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

ANY SUGGESTIONS?

it is more clear in the attached picture of [excel template showing user form and macro button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t88sB.png)

Comment: Where is `txt_script` defined? Does it contain a value when the macro runs?

Comment: yes. the ```txt_script``` is the input variable. ("Script Name" in the picture).  The Get commandbutton gives the Vlookup-ed value based on the ```text_script``` input.